# D3 linear gradient to geojson path according its value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I have geojson file with line and each line has a different value (for example different speed) I would like to assign gradient colors to these lines according their speed values. Is it possible? I've found descriptions only for gradient for whole page or div.

My code:

```
var speed = d3.json("speed.geojson", function (error, data){
            svg.append("svg")
            .selectAll ("path")
            .data(data.features)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr ("d", path)
            .style ("stroke", "green") //how to insert gradient here?
            .style ("stroke-width", 2)
            });
```

My geojson:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 0,
            "properties": {
                "id": null,
                "speed": 5
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        16.370509236468372,
                        48.212650342706375
                    ],
                    [
                        16.37508962063344,
                        48.22070071487528
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 1,
            "properties": {
                "id": null,
                "speed": 6
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        16.376061217274515,
                        48.2293062851248
                    ],
                    [
                        16.39021876833018,
                        48.21639792975052
                    ],
                    [
                        16.39021876833018,
                        48.21639792975052
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 2,
            "properties": {
                "id": null,
                "speed": 2
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        16.38369519088296,
                        48.2021015791747
                    ],
                    [
                        16.391329164491406,
                        48.21251154318622
                    ],
                    [
                        16.390079968810024,
                        48.21639792975052
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 3,
            "properties": {
                "id": null,
                "speed": 9
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        16.376061217274515,
                        48.22944508464495
                    ],
                    [
                        16.374950821113288,
                        48.22083951439543
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 4,
            "properties": {
                "id": 3,
                "speed": 7
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        16.37078683550868,
                        48.21292794174668
                    ],
                    [
                        16.383417591842655,
                        48.2021015791747
                    ],
                    [
                        16.383417591842655,
                        48.2021015791747
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear) for this. A scale maps values in the input domain (e.g. speed) to values in the output domain (e.g. colour). It works like this.

```
 var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxSpeed]).range(["red", "green"]);
 ...
 svg.append("svg")
        .selectAll ("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr ("d", path)
        .style ("stroke", function(d) { return scale(d.properties.speed); })
        .style ("stroke-width", 2);
```

You can of course adjust the colours. To determine the maximum speed in your data, you may find the helper [`d3.max`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_max) helpful:

```
var maxSpeed = d3.max(data.features, function(d) { return d.properties.speed; });
```